# How to access component data from inside mapState()?

Tags: vue.js, arrow-functions

Depending on the value of my prop `buttonType`, I want to retrieve different store variables:

```
...mapState({
  backgroundColor: state => this.buttonType === 'primary'
    ? state.primary_button.background_color
    : state.secondary_button.background_color
})
```

This doesn't work though, because arrows functions have their own `this`. So I tried:

```
...mapState({
  backgroundColor: function(state) {
    return this.buttonType === 'primary'
    ? state.primary_button.background_color
    : state.secondary_button.background_color
  }
})
```

Getting this error:

> Expected method shorthand

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split this into three props: `primaryColor` and `secondaryColor` (using `mapState`), and then a separate computed prop that returns one of them based on `buttonType`:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      primaryColor: state => state.primary_button.background_color,
      secondaryColor: state => state.secondary_button.background_color,
    }),
    backgroundColor() {
      return this.buttonType === 'primary'
        ? this.primaryColor
        : this.secondaryColor
    }
  }
}
```

Or if you just want one prop, you could reference the store's state directly:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    backgroundColor() {
      return this.buttonType === 'primary'
        ? this.$store.state.primary_button.background_color
        : this.$store.state.secondary_button.background_color
    }
  }
}
```